# How to use SAML based authentication in IONIC application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, saml-2.0

I need to implement SSO authentication using SAML based authentication in our IONIC app for iOS/Andoid.
Here is following doubt in my mind while working on that:
1. Is it possible that SAML supports IONIC Framework?
2. If not supported then any alternative way to do SSO authentication in IONIC.Any samle code for that?

It will be appreciate if you provide useful answer.

Thanks & regards
Ravi

Comment: also looking for a solution, but it's not easy to reach. I've found useful resources on telerik site: http://www.telerik.com/forums/cordova-sso-login
Please let me know if you have succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hybrid implementation, where we open the connection to SAML url and keep intercepting the url changes for login key.

Some sample code for login.

```js
var options = { location: 'no', toolbar: 'no', clearcache: 'yes' };

var signInUrl; // Generate your signINUrl with appending detail like client id , redirection url etc. 
    
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(signInUrl, '_blank', options)
        .then(function(event) {
          // success
        })
        .catch(function(event) {
          // error
});  // Prompt user to login 

// Interceptor to find the hash key while redirections are active.

$scope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function (e, event) {
      var key = event.url.split('code=')[1];
      if(key) {
        console.log('got key');
        //hide spinners, 
        //logic to create user session for login.
        //Can use localstorage to store key.
        // Change state to starting page. 
        // clear any histroy/ prevent go back to login controller. 
      } else {
        console.log('loading', event.url);
        //keep on waiting. 
      }
});
```

```js
$scope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function (e, event) {
   // Handler Spinners. 
});

$scope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function (e, event) {
   // Handler Spinners & erros. 
});
```

When user opens the app check for the Key in Localstorage if its present create a session or else call the above login function and after success store the key to localStorage.

To logout, just hit the logout url , there is not need to intercept url's or response and just clear the localStorage value.

- Clear the cookies & localStorage before calling the login function.

Answer (score -3):

SAML is not yet supported for Ionic. For this application we recommend password vaulting.

https://www.bitium.com/ionic-saml-provider

Comment: The fact that bitium doesn't support saml for ionic doesn't mean it can't be done